# How to properly animate a constraint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am using autolayout and I am trying to slide views on and off the screen. I have tried several methods, some from stackoverflow and some from Apple docs, but nothing works. The view  just pop on screen, no matter what duration I use when animating them on.

As you can see below, I have tried it out several ways. Nothing works. Hiding and showing they both just pop on and off screen (i.e. not animating).

```
-(void)hideButtons {

[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Ensures that all pending layout operations have been completed


[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
    self.leftSideConstraint.constant = 300;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}

-(void)showButtons {

//[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Ensures that all pending layout operations have been completed

self.leftSideConstraint.constant = 87;
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `self.leftSideConstraint` was added to `self.view` and not to its superview or some other view? If the latter, then I believe that is your problem. I think you will need to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the view that has that constraint.

EDIT: Actually, you can call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on `self.view` since it will propagate up the view hierarchy, but I believe you will need to `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview.

Comment: self.leftSideConstraint belongs to a subview of self.view